# Javascript update table with timer(hidden in csv file)

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv

everybody. I have an interesting question. Would be grateful for your help. Working on solution to one task:

> Implement a financials ticker grid using the CSV data provided Initial
>   View
>
> Load and parse the data in snapshot.csv into a model.
>
> Render a grid based on that data to the DOM.
>
> Write an engine to work through deltas.csv and emit update messages to
>   parse.
>
> When only a number exists on a line, that amount of time in
>   milliseconds should be waited until processing the next set of deltas.
>   When the last set of deltas is processed, return to the start of the
>   file and repeat.
>
> Each set of deltas should be merged into the existing dataset and then
>   propagated to the DOM in the most efficient manner possible.
>
> Provide notification that an item has been updated via a visual flare
>   in the UI.

My path:
I've managed to load the snapshot.csv, parse it, create table, then(using promises), upload the second file delta.csv, parse it, trying to update table, but struggling to create timer function to update the table according to the amount of miliseconds in the delta csv file. Thanks in advance for your advice))I'm learning javascript, and looking for challenges, this looked like an interesting one.

```js
function CSVToArray( strData, strDelimiter ){
  strDelimiter = (strDelimiter || ",");
  var objPattern = new RegExp(
      (
          // Delimiters.
          "(\\" + strDelimiter + "|\\r?\\n|\\r|^)" +

          // Quoted fields.
          "(?:\"([^\"]*(?:\"\"[^\"]*)*)\"|" +

          // Standard fields.
          "([^\"\\" + strDelimiter + "\\r\\n]*))"
      ),
      "gi"
      );
  var arrData = [[]];
  var arrMatches = null;
  while (arrMatches = objPattern.exec( strData )){
      var strMatchedDelimiter = arrMatches[ 1 ];
      if (
          strMatchedDelimiter.length &&
          strMatchedDelimiter !== strDelimiter
          ){
          arrData.push( [] );
      }
      var strMatchedValue;
      if (arrMatches[ 2 ]){
          strMatchedValue = arrMatches[ 2 ].replace(
              new RegExp( "\"\"", "g" ),
              "\""
              );
      } else {
          // We found a non-quoted value.
          strMatchedValue = arrMatches[ 3 ];
      }
      arrData[ arrData.length - 1 ].push( strMatchedValue );
  }

  // Return the parsed data.
  return( arrData );
    }

function httpGet(url) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.onload = function() {
      if (this.status == 200) {
        resolve(this.response);
      } else {
        var error = new Error(this.statusText);
        error.code = this.status;
        reject(error);
      }
    };
    xhr.onerror = function() {
      reject(new Error("Network Error"));
    };
    xhr.send();
  });

}

var r1,r2
httpGet('snapshot.csv').then(function(result) {
  r1 = CSVToArray(result);
  createTable(r1);
  return httpGet('deltas.csv')
}).then(function(result2) {
     r2 = CSVToArray(result2);
     updateTable(r2)
   });

var hInterval = null;
var k = 0;
var iteration=0;
function updateTable(how) {
    var myTable = document.getElementById('myTable');
    var j=1;
    var watch_dog=0;
    var x = document.getElementById("myTable").rows[0].cells;
    console.log(x);
    while(j<myTable.rows.length) {

        if (typeof(how[k]) !== "undefined") { //

            var startPos = 2; //In file we have broken data (some time 6 columns some time 5)
            if (how[k].length === 5)
                startPos = 1;

            var valueAdded=0; //How much value changed
            for (var i = startPos; i < startPos + 3; i++) {

                var value = how[k][i];

                if (typeof(value) !== "undefined") {
                    valueAdded++;
                    if (value.length > 0) {
                        if (startPos === 2)
                            myTable.rows[j].cells[i].innerHTML = value;
                        else
                            myTable.rows[j].cells[i + 1].innerHTML = value;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (valueAdded>0) //if some values changed we are increment j
             j++;

            k++; //Increment global row pointer


        } else {
            //Restart when we finished
           iteration=1;
            k=0;
            break;
        }
    }
}


function createTable(now) {
 var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    // create elements <table> and a <tbody>
    var tbl     = document.createElement("table");
    var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");
    tbl.setAttribute("id","myTable");
    // cells creation
    for (var j = 0; j < now.length-1; j++) {
        // table row creation
        var row = document.createElement("tr");

        for (var i = 0; i < now[0].length; i++) {
            // create element <td> and text node
            //Make text node the contents of <td> element
            // put <td> at end of the table row
            var cell = document.createElement("td");
            var cellText = document.createTextNode(now[j][i]);

            cell.appendChild(cellText);
            row.appendChild(cell);
        }

        //row added to end of table body
        tblBody.appendChild(row);
    }

    // append the <tbody> inside the <table>
    tbl.appendChild(tblBody);
    // put <table> in the <body>
    body.appendChild(tbl);
    // tbl border attribute to
    tbl.setAttribute("border", "2");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Application</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
     <meta name="description" content="Demo project">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <style type="text/css"></style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p>Let the game begin!</p>
 </body>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Project files:
https://dw3i9sxi97owk.cloudfront.net/uploads/jobAttachments/150928161919_pph.zip

Answer (score 1):

You could write a recursive function that processes one row at a time, then set's up the timeout to process the next row in X seconds. The code below is just kind of pseudo, it doesn't use your variables or anything... but hopefully you can get the idea from this. It's a recursive function that calls itself for the next row after waiting the amount of time.

```
function processRow(row, waitTime) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        //do your row stuff here

        //move on to the next row, look at it's wait time and pass that along
        var nextRow = row+1,
            nextWaitTime = nextRow.waitTime;
        processRow(nextRow, nextWaitTime);
    }, waitTime);
}

//run the first instance
var firstRow = 1,
    firstWait = firstRow.wait;
processRow(firstRow, firstWait);
```

Comment: Thanks for advice, Caleb. I was thinking about the recursion. I'll deep into this topic more. 
I'also concerned how to get this amount o miliseconds from (deltas scv) and update the table according to this csv (it has miliseconds update time, and data for three cells) cause sometimes it updates not the appropriate cells(((

Comment: For sure, I'd recommend passing in that data to the function and using it there, so adding another variable to pass in like 'rowData' etc, and then you'd have a local copy of the data passed in to the function, rather than accessing the global variables which may change over time as you crawl the CSV.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve the same result, but using loops, without recursion?

Comment: You could potentially do a while loop, and do your increment inside a timeout, but that may lock up the page and not allow you scroll/interact until it was done handling the whole csv.

Comment: Hey, just had another thought, you could do it all with a for loop, and for each item, set a timeout so that it updates in it's own delay plus all other delays so far. The first row would update after 100 ms for example, and the second would update after 200+100 ms to account for the 100ms that needed to elapse before it started counting down.

Comment: Caleb, thanks I will try this path with for loop as well!)))